# Equation $2n^2=m^2+1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given the equation
$$2n^2=m^2+1$$
Is there a general solution?

---

since $m$ is odd for example  $$2\cdot5^2=7^2+1$$ $$2\cdot29^2=41^2+1$$

Any hint would be appreciation.

Comment: Search Pell's equation.

Answer (score 3):

There are infinitely many solutions. You will understand where they come from once I write down this little table for you:
$$
n = \quad 5 \quad 12 \quad 29 \quad 70  \quad ...\\
m = \quad 7 \quad 17 \quad 41 \quad 99 \quad ...\\
$$

If you have not yet understood the pattern : the number in each top row is the sum of the numbers in the previous column (e.g. $70 = 41+29$), and the difference between numbers in the same column is the top number of previous column ($e.g. 99-70 = 29$).

Now, you can see how to continue this table and obtain infinitely many solutions. I would encourage you to find an algebraic proof of this fact.

Answer (score 1):

If

$2n^2=m^2+1$

then

$2(3n+2m)^2 = 18n^2 + 14nm +8m^2$

$=9(m^2 + 1) + 14nm + 8m^2$

$=9(m^2+1) + 14nm + 8(2n^2-1)$

$=16n^2 + 14nm + 9m^2 + 1$

$=(4n+3m)^2 + 1$

so we have (1,1) -> (5,7) -> (29,41) etc.